# GET request in Express to match array parameter

Tags: node.js, express

I'm struggling with routing in Express.  This works:

```
app.get('/customers/bar/:bar/buzz/:buzz', customers.foo);
```

i.e. requests like this match (return 200 code):

```
curl -is http://localhost:3000/customers/bar/blah/buzz/blah -H 'accept: text/plain'
```

but how do I change my `app.get(…)` to accept an array of parameters for `bar` e.g. matching a form that would have inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="bar[]" value="test1">
<input type="text" name="bar[]" value="test2">
<input type="text" name="bar[]" value="test3">
```

I can't see anything in the documentation that demonstrates how this would work.  Thanks.

Comment: When you want to use arrays I recommend using `POST`. If you *have to* use `GET` with routing, you probably have to go with something like `/customers/bar/:array` and split the `array` param accordingly.

Comment: Nice question did not know that you could send arrays in a get request.

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892101/array-as-parameter-in-get-request-in-postman