# Array as parameter in GET request in Postman

Tags: node.js, api, postman

I have to send array of ids in GET request as paramenter.How can I test it in Postman(google chrome extension for API testing)?

The scenario is I have url, *www.something.com/activity/poi_ids*

poi_ids should conatain arrays of ids like [316,318]

At api side using express,

```
app.get('/activity/:poi_ids',function(req,res){
    var poi_ids = req.params.poi_ids;
    .......
    .......
});
```

[I have looked into it but it is only for post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unstructured text. If you want to "send an array" then you'll need to design some way to encode it and then write JavaScript to decode it.

For example:

```
GET /activity/316-318
```

and

```
var poi_ids = req.params.poi_ids.split("-");
```

Answer (score 8):

you can send them via query params ..
in your http query params assign all values to same variables like

```
GET activity?pid=12&pid=23&pid=34
```

and then inside your express get it like

```
var ids=req.query.pid; //[12,23,34]
```